# avoiding implicit copying with a disabled copy constructor

Tags: c++, copy-constructor

Suppose you have a class NonCopyable

```
class NonCopyable
{
public:
   NonCopyable(int n){}
   ~NonCopyable(){}
   [...]

private:
   [members...]

private:
   NonCopyable( const NonCopyable& ); //disabled (no definition)
   NonCopyable& operator= ( const NonCopyable& ); //disabled (no definition)
};
```

For this class, it's illogical to have copies of it, thus the copy constructor and assignment operator are disabled.

However, when you need a vector of NonCopyables objects:

```
std::vector<NonCopyable> m_V;
int n;
m_V.push_back(NonCopyable(n));
```

Here, you implicitly invoke the copy constructor.

I've been taught to solve this problem by using pointers to those objects instead of the objects themselves. But this is annoying both in use and in performance, because you have to dynamically allocate those objects with new()...

My question:
Is there a way around this? What's a common solution to this problem?

Comment: Your question seems to be "how can I use a non-copyable object in a situation where I need to copy that object?"...

Comment: Serious question, if it's illogical to have copies outside a vector, why would it be better to have copies if they're inside a vector? :)

Comment: it's not supposed to be a copy, that's my point. I want to supply the vector with a unique object, if you get me

Comment: @xcrypt: But of course it's a copy.  The vector contains a copy of the original object!

Comment: @OliCharlesworth I'm not stating it's not a copy. I'm saying it's not supposed to be a copy, I want the vector to have unique objects

Comment: @Oli: `vector` in C++03 has an unfortunate and non-essential limitation, which is that the only way to get objects into it is to copy them there. xcrypt doesn't *want* copies of objects: `vector` is a convenient way to memory-manage a runtime-variable number of objects, but in C++03 it's not as convenient as it is in C++11.

Comment: @xcrypt I've mentioned this in a separate comment, but my question really belongs here. How can NonCopyable be unique unless there is only ever one object of it? In that case, putting it in a vector doesn't make sense to me. I realize I'm probably being a noob here. Please do clarify. Thanks!

Comment: @batbrat He only wants one object, the one in the vector. The solution would be to construct the object in-place inside the vector which is not possible in C++03 (C++11 has move semantics and emplace_back)

Comment: @pezcode Thanks for clarifying. It seems he wants to use std::vector only for memory management. Is that it? That explains the suggestion of using smart pointers instead.

Comment: @batbrat: NonCopyable doesn't mean there's only one of it, ever (like a singleton). It just means that no two are "the same", and so it doesn't make sense to set one object equal to another (copy assignment), or construct a clone of an existing object (copy ctor).

Comment: @SteveJessop That's what I thought initially, however xcrypt used the term unique in a comment, which left me more than confused. So this is just to ensure that it is a vector of distinct objects. Thanks a ton for clarifying.

Comment: @batbrat Sorry, I phrased it poorly there. I meant unique as in "not a copy of". It doesn't mean that the vector can't contain multiple equivalent objects though. The only restriction is that it is illegal to make copies.

Comment: @xcrypt, it's fine. I just had a hard time interpreting it. Thanks for clarifying it!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

C++11 has a solution that applies to many non-copyable classes: make the class movable (instead of copyable), and use `emplace_back` to add new elements to the vector.

If you need to fudge something with C++03, perhaps you can find a way to implement copying of "empty" NonCopyable objects (and use Luchian's idea of restricting this operation), and also find a way to implement `swap`. Then you can do:

```
std::vector<NonCopyable> m_V;
int n;
m_V.push_back(NonCopyable());
NonCopyable(n).swap(m_V.back());
```

Comment: Might be a noob question, but I've always worked with C++03. How can I start working with C++11?

Comment: Check your compiler's documentation, for example with gcc it's `-std=c++0x`.

Answer (score 1):

You can make the `vector` a friend of the class:

```
class NonCopyable
{
   friend std::vector<NonCopyable>;
public:
   NonCopyable(int n){}
   ~NonCopyable(){}

private:
   NonCopyable( const NonCopyable& ) {}; 
   NonCopyable& operator= ( const NonCopyable& ) {}; 
};
```

or you could have a `vector` of smart pointers to the class.

EDIT:

I might have misunderstood the question. If you don't want copies of the class (my original guess was that you didn't want making copies to be publicly accessible), you should definetely use smart pointers.

Comment: You also need a definition for those copies.

Comment: Making the `vector` a `friend` will just cause linker errors if there really isn't a implementation for the copy constructor.

Comment: @SteveJessop I just copy-pasted the code, but yes, they do need definitions.

Comment: If a class is noncopyable, it's usually because it makes little sense for it to be copyable in any way... so meaningful implementation of copy constructor and assignment operator will probably be impossible to come up with. Thus, making `vector` a friend will be of little avail.

Comment: @Fanael I understood that the op doesn't want it to be copied, not that it's uncopyable. I can't find an example of a situation where it's impossible to copy an object...

Comment: I have a noob question. How does making the vector a friend prevent the copy-constructor issue. I really don't understand. If I should be looking at my books again or looking at some resources, point me at them. However, some explanation in addition to that would be very welcome. Thanks!

Comment: @batbrat prevent what? It just means that `vector` is allowed to make copies of the class.

Comment: @LuchianGrigore: Do you know any sensible implementation of copy operation for, for example, a `scoped_ptr`?

Comment: @batbrat making the vector friend will allow it to access private data from the class. Thus, it can access it's copy constructor, and use it (providing that it has a definition)

Comment: @LuchianGrigore My question was poorly phrased. If the vector is allowed to make copies of the class, isn't the uniqueness requirement violated? Additionally, is this the only way to solve it nicely outside of C++11?

Comment: @batbrat I also missunderstood the question (I think). I'd use smart pointers - as I said in my edit.

Comment: @LuchianGrigore I don't know that much about smart pointers, but wouldn't you have to allocate the objects they point to with new()? (explicitly or implicitly). Because that's a solution I'm trying to avoid

Comment: Thanks for clarifying xcrypt, @LuchianGrigore. I believe that one can use pointers or smart pointers to solve it. I've not used smart pointers a lot, but I know that the main advantage is ref-counting and off-loading memory management. How'd that be important here? Besides, I'm a little lost on the uniqueness issue as well. The vector cannot contain more than one NonCopyable object otherwise it wouldn't be unique, right?

Comment: @batbrat It may contain more than one NonCopyable object. It may even contain two equivalent NonCopyable objects. However, a NonCopyable object may not be copied. About the smart pointers, they do feature ref-counting and more, but they still have to point to an object. Which means that either you would have to allocate one on the stack or on the heap. If you'd allocate it on the heap, you'd use new() or something similar, but I want to avoid that. However, if you make one on the stack, when the function body has ended, it will pop from the stack (call it's destructor), (continued)

Comment: (continued) Thus the smart pointer that the vector contains will point to a non-existing object. So unless smart pointers have the ability to prevent the stack from popping that object, or if they copy that object (but we can exclude that since it's not copyable), or unless it points to an object in the heap (we can exclude that too since I don't want that), I don't see how smart pointers can solve the problem.

Comment: @xcrypt they can't if you avoid objects on the heap.